# permission denied in jenkins(docker in docker)

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration

I want to run docker command in Jenkins. I run jenkins

```
sudo docker run -d -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home     -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000     -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock 4oh4/jenkins-docker
```

and I run docker pull ubuntu in jenkins

```
#docker exec -it jenkins bash                  
jenkins#docker pull ubuntu in jenkins
```

and I get this error

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/images/create?fromImage=ubuntu&tag=latest: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

After some search I found two solution

1:)chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock

2:)sudo usermod -aG docker

solution 1 is worked but I think it is not secure. solution 2 is not work because I run jenkins in docker and I do not have jenkins user.

what is the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: can you try with `docker run --privileged`

Comment: I will test it.Is it safe to give priviledge to one container?

Comment: If you are mounting docker sock then it's mandatory

Comment: You do not need `--privileged` mode just to use the host's Docker socket, and it's not especially safe.  Especially since `chmod 0777` works, this is nothing more or less than a filesystem permission issue.